# How can I create a fly-over waypoint in the G1000?

Tags: g1000

How do I make the G1000 fly *over* a user waypoint rather than fly *by* it, therefore not sequencing to the next waypoint until the aircraft has overflown the current one?

I’ve tried ATK Offset but with a sharp turn to the next leg (>120 degrees) this still does not work.

Comment: The OBS function will let you manually fly over the waypoint, but using that technique isn't actually toggling the waypoint property. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Have you looked at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsA3k3Ss74M)?

Comment: The video discusses the use of ATK Offset which only works in set circumstances (i.e. on ~>120degs). It also describes simply putting the autopilot into heading hold mode (i.e. ignore the gps which will still auto sequence to the next waypoint at the moment of turn anticaption). Unfortunately this does not appear to be a function that the G1000 is capable of.